# How should one remember Allah while programming?

Tags: work, science, behavior, muslim-practices, profession

I'm fairly new in islamic study. I just read that we, muslim, should focus on our imaan and taqwa before anything else including science and technology and should be able to relate the study to the almighty god, Allah SWT. But I just dont get how should I do such things when I write code. What should I do in order to be capable of doing it?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Don't leave your prayer which is faraz,
I can relate to my self while doing some project time pass very quickly and get late for the prayer. and ask Allah for saving our Imaan